# this code but the part href='allowbook.php?giv=<?php echo $id ?>'

Tags: php

**

> ' title='View Booking
>   Status'> NewRequest "; } else if ($st ==1){  echo"' title='View
>
> ### Booking Status'> HallBooked "; } ?>

**---------------

Comment: <?php 
                if($st ==0){
                 echo"<a class='btn btn-danger  btn-sm' href='allowbook.php?giv=<?php echo $id ?>' title='View Booking Status'>
                NewRequest 
                </a>";
                }else if ($st ==1){
                 echo"<a class='btn btn-success  btn-sm' href='allowbook.php?giv=<?php  $id ?>' title='View Booking Status'>
                HallBooked 
                </a>";
                }
                ?>

Comment: the part in code href='allowbook.php?giv=<?php echo $id ?>' cant contain the value while referred on next page

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, also please check the formatting options available when you create/edit an answer.

Comment: i am saying that i have running a php code in my echo statement i have printing a div .i div part am using href tag (href='allowbook.php?giv=<?php echo $id ?>' ) like this but it cant contain id value ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue in your code could be one of the following:

#### 1: $id is undefined:

Your code could simply have a syntax error when defining the variable id.

#### 2: You are trying to get the id from the database

I am not 100% sure where the `$id` came from, however you could be meaning `$row['id']`. As in the one you fetch from the database. In that case you need to put `$row['id']`.

Other than those two possibilities we really can't do much for you if you don't give us all of the code however, I really hope this helps you and if you would like to clarify anything else please add it to your question.